# Dockerfile error when trying to dockerize Angular - no such file or directory

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to Dockerize and deploy an Angular app. I have the following:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /dist/nexct-approval-ui /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then I run:

```
docker stop /ng-nexct-approval-ui-container
docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t ng-nexct-approval-ui-image:latest "."
```

I get he following output:

```
/ng-nexct-approval-ui-container
Sending build context to Docker daemon  541.9MB
Step 1/12 : FROM node
latest: Pulling from library/node
Digest: sha256:a6be25f2f9b8af240ee0b50aeee089bc66c23dfe95053a4de289b8d9efebdc44
Status: Image is up to date for node:latest
 ---> 37ad18cd8bd1
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a497790a47a4
Step 3/12 : COPY package.json package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 784e7d4b48f6
Step 4/12 : RUN npm install --silent
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 63fd9d88955f
Step 5/12 : COPY . .
 ---> 9028e45e0701
Step 6/12 : RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
 ---> Running in dca7a1305fa9
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.d26681d378262fd3296d.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.ca016a6f12d7e632666f.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es2015.0dae8cbc97194c7caed4.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.0dae8cbc97194c7caed4.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.d2d6ea2818487d59afe5.js (main) 1.86 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.d2d6ea2818487d59afe5.js (main) 1.98 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.f52187462d1cfca0d78e.css (styles) 62.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-22T10:14:36.958Z - Hash: d17c8f049f83f75a6b04 - Time: 69588ms

WARNING in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es5. Budget 2 MB was not met by 168 kB with a total of 2.16 MB.
Removing intermediate container dca7a1305fa9
 ---> f395c253b4ed
Step 7/12 : FROM nginx:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:ee8c35a6944eb3cc415cd4cbeddef13927895d4ffa50b976886e3abe48b3f35a
Status: Image is up to date for nginx:alpine
 ---> ecd67fe340f9
Step 8/12 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in e9a249ce0b36
Removing intermediate container e9a249ce0b36
 ---> 453af4305629
Step 9/12 : RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
 ---> Running in ba40b25e4973
Removing intermediate container ba40b25e4973
 ---> f813f1d121b1
Step 10/12 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 ---> a6c544d4efdd
Step 11/12 : COPY /dist/nexct-approval-ui /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder401838835/dist/nexct-approval-ui: no such file or directory
```

**Question**

How do I fix the `no such file or directory` error?

I think this is related to the `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`.

Thanks

Comment: Where does the `/dist/nexct-approval-ui` directory comes from ? Is it generated on your first stage or do you have it locally ?

Comment: If i rung `ng build` locally it generates it. However, I am now trying to generate the `dist` folder by running `ng build` in the Dockerfile. So maybe I am doing that incorrectly.

Comment: You must reference your first stage when you do the `COPY` otherwise docker will look on your local folder only. Use `COPY --from=0`. For reference https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

Comment: You execute the build command in the first container after setting the working directory to 
`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`. Unless you have instructed your build script to do otherwise, you should find the /dist/ in the working directory.

Comment: Alternatively you can add the `--output-path` option to your `ng build` command and specify any path you'd like, as @user3362334 suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I believe you are trying to achieve is a multi-stage-build:

**Stage 1:** build the node app in the node container - this sould create a /dist/ directory somewhere in the container
**Stage 2:** Copy the built node app from the /dist/ directory to an nginx container that would serve your app.

And you are right: the problem is here `COPY /dist/nexct-approval-ui /usr/share/nginx/html`. This line will try to copy `/dist/nexct-approval-ui` from your OS, not from the container that built the /dist/ folder in Stage 1.

To refer to the image created in stage 1, try this:

```
COPY --from=0 /path-to-your-dist-in-the-node-container/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

In order to tell `ng build` to generate the `/dist/` directory in a path of your choice rather than the current working directory, the `--output-path` can be used:

```
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=/path-to-your-dist-in-the-node-container/
```

*Credits to @user336233*

Comment: Hi Neo, thanks for the answer, I think you are spot on.  How do I know what the `/path-to-your-dist-in-the-node-container/` is?

Comment: I think it may be the following, I am just testing it: `COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/dist/nexct-approval-ui /usr/share/nginx/html`

Comment: In your case that should be /dist/nexct-approval-ui. If not try setting the value in ng build command like I suggested

Comment: @user3362334, I have set the build cmd as you suggested, but I get the same error:  `RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=/dist/nexct-approval-ui`

Comment: Nope that didn't work. `Step 11/12 : COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/dist/nexct-approval-ui /usr/share/nginx/html`, gives this errror: `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d0eccfbfc3b17610bf71e236eb5e3bde04ee9b8551afae9a57496aa94af6684f/merged/usr/src/app/dist/nexct-approval-ui: no such file or directory`.

Comment: Here's what's working for me: RUN ng build --configuration production --output-path=/dist when building the image and COPY --from=build /dist /usr/share/nginx/html when copying it to the NGINX

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved by user3362334 and Neo Anderson, thank you.

Here is my working solution.

```
# stage 1
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=/dist

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=0 /dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check "outputPath" property in you angular.json. That's the place where the folder name that will be built inside the dist folder is specified. I guess it isn't set to *nexct-approval-ui*, thus the folder doesn't exist and docker throws an error.

**EDIT:** Another option would be to specify the output path in your build command in Dockerfile like this:

```
ng build -prod --output-path=[your path here]
```

Comment: It is set to:  `"outputPath": "dist/nexct-approval-ui",`

Comment: If I change the line to the following, I still get the same error. `RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=/dist/nexct-approval-ui`.  Because it's the same location. I think the issue is because of the prepended `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder782794717`. But I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: If I look in the created images, there is no `/var/lib/docker` directory.

Comment: Thank you that worked, in conjunction with your recommendation above. So I chenged to `RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=/dist` and `COPY --from=build /dist /usr/share/nginx/html`.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Now I get a different error, but I think it's related to the `--from`.  `invalid from flag value build: pull access denied for build, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

Comment: aha, the reason for that is that I had 'FROM node:12-alpine as build' on top of my Dockerfile, so I mapped the container to name build, in your case 0 works, because it's the default name